# React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string -- index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get my content to render on my homepage, but getting the following error in the browser console. I'm using the update create-react-app v4:

> js:1375 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './sass/main.scss';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('cantainer'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './sass/main.scss';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/app';
import Home from './components/pages/home';

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
  </Route>
);
```

./components/app

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your App file ?

Comment: Just update edited my files @SimoMatavulj

Comment: @Arup Rakshit. How can make it valid? inside the <Route>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export it as a function component from `App.js`. And `<Route>` inside `<Route>` also needs to be written as :

```
export default () => (
  <Route
    path="/"
    render={props => (
      <App {...props}>
        <Home />
      </App>
    )}
  />
);
```

What you have is not a valid JSX at all.

Comment: Alright, Why that just curious. To in learning more and what i did wrong